# Sharepoint Site Missing after failed patch

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I attempted to apply update KB2553018 to Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 (via Windows Update) running on 2008 Server (32bit).

The updated failed with Event ID 20 in the System event log: “Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800706be: Update for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (KB2553018).”

After reboot, when I go to http://servername, I get the following, when I would normally get our sharepoint site:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 Date: Sun, 06 Nov 2011 21:33:47 GMT Connection: close

I can open Windows Sharepoint Administration, and I don’t see any indication of the previous site.

When I open ISM, I do see the site created, and I see the virtual directories under it.

However, I’m not sure where to go from here. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint will only install patches from windows update or WSUS if you installed it in "Stand-alone" mode.  Any other installation requires you to manually apply the patches.

Even if you are in a "Stand-alone" installation, it is still recommended to not use the automatic updating service.

Re-run the configuration wizard and attempt the update again.

If it fails you can try this command:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

If you continue to have issues, you review the upgrade log file for "failed" or "error" entries.  If you find those, clear those up and re-run the above forced install command.

Two other methods for grabbing more information about the install can be used to track down errors as well:

1. Enable windows installer logging by using the MSI switch `/l*v` or follow this MS Article to enable it via registry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300
2. Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) which will allow you to watch which local resources (files, folder, reg keys, and external processes) are being used/called and if there are any failures.